# IIS get back default config

Tags: iis-7, iis

How to reset IIS to get back to the default configuration (no applications installed)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If its IIS7+, remove and re-add the role.

Otherwise:

Follow [this procedure](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/325889) from Microsoft on how to remove and reinstall IIS 5.0, 5.1 and 6.0